What is the correct way to approximate the diffusion rate of gases in water as a function of temperature?
In applied chemistry/physics, I see the diffusion coefficient of gases in water being approximated by various ways.
Arah and Stephen 1998 for instance use a linear Dw(T) with 0 intercept for methane and dioxygen. Trying to reproduce this fit using data from the CRC handbook (2016) (T=[283., 288., 293., 298., 303.]K, Dw = [1.26e-09, 1.45e-09, 1.67e-09, 1.91e-09, 2.17e-09] m2/s) fails miserably. A linear regression gives us a non-linear intercept, which is odd because diffusion should be at 0 when the temperature is at 0K. Thus the linear approximation is terrible.
Trying to fit an Arrhenius function does not work too well (the model appears to be overparameterized based on the condition number of the covariance matrix of estimated parameters). It appears that parameters of the Stokes-Einstein equation are not that easy to come by.
Is there a satisfying way of approximating the diffusion coefficient of a gas in water as a function of temperature in a reasonable range (say 10C to 40C)?
Thanks!

What would regression give at zero K isn't terribly relevant when there's no liquid water, even overcooled, anywhere close to it... but this indeed doesn't look linear.

Indeed. For diffusion in air, I see $D_a = D_a^0 (\frac{T}{T_0})^{1.82}$ being used, which is seemingly also a better fit (visually) for $D_w$, however the problem appears to be overparameterized still from looking at the results of scipy's curve fit.

can you also post the results of the arrhenius fitting in terms of relevant fitting parameters? This would give us an idea of the overparametrization taking place!

Also, note that a non-linear behaviour is expected in the low temperature regime due to the progressive retardation in the average molecular motions (at some point rotations and vibrations would probably start to play a role and in the low temperature regime you should take in account more sophisticated theories of diffusion e.g. Eyring's theory or statistical mechanics theories in general)

Thanks for your insight. So brute-fitting a Arrhenius equation in the form $D=D_{inf} e^{-\frac{E_a}{R}(1/T-1/298.15)}$ to the data in the post (which is CO$2$ btw) using scipy.optimize.curve_fit yields $D{inf}=4.86 \times 10^{-6}$ m$^2$/s and $E_a= 19.43$ kJ/mol. The condition number of the covariance matrix is of the order of $10^{20}$. Your comment prompted me to try fitting a line to the Arrhenius plot $\log(D) \sim 1/T$, which I understand is the standard way (I am a biologist, not a chemist) appears to be much better, yielding similar $E_a$ and $D_{inf}=6.14 \times 10^{-6}$.

Also, I run a quick fitting using OriginPro for the dataset you provided. The parameters do exhibiy a fair amount of dependency but consider that we are taking in account a really short interval of temperatures it is expected! Fitting in the linear form as you did is the standard (and simplest) way. I checked also some other trends for $\ce{H2}$ and $\ce{CH4}$ and they do seem to work fine. I think that in the high temperature limit an Arrhenius Plot would be perfect. I will post a complete answer tomorrow because here its 2.00 a.m!

also, be sure to consider that $log(D)$ is the natural logarithm, otherwise the result would be quite messed up in terms of values. The values you provided do seem reasonable both in terms of activation energy (it's comparable to the molecular vibrations  and to the solvation free energy c.ca in terms of orders of magnitude) and limiting diffusion coefficient at high T.

Have you tried the Stokes-Einstein law $D=RT/(6\pi \eta r)$ where $\eta$ is the viscosity of the liquid water at temp T, and $r$ the radius of gas?

@porphyrin I have a feeling that for these molecules that have dimensions comparable to that of water, the S-E equation alone could be a bit too simple (the approximation of continuum solvent may not be fulfilled). Maybe some micro friction corrected SE would be suitable.

@Giuseppe Basile, yes I agree but this eqn. often works quite well when it seems that it should not. It might, however,  give the correct form as viscosity is also temperature dependent.

yes but then the fit should be on $D(T,\eta (T))$,no? If he wants to do a fit and treats eta as a constant things could get sketchy, if, instead, he uses an explicit form of $\eta(T)$ and then fits the data, maybe it'd work tho. I agree with you that the SE equation works incredibly well in most applications, but at fixed temperature, usally (or am I getting something mixed up?)

Thanks for the discussion! GiuseppeBasile: my fit was indeed using the natural log of D. @porphyrin, I did encounter mentions of the SE equation, but I had the intuition that it may be overkill ? $\eta(T)$ is readily available on wikipedia, but molecular radii not so much? Can't attach an image to this comment, but I tried fitting SE to the CO2 data with $r$ as a free parameter. Looks good to me, not much better than Arrhenius in appearance, but well conditioned. I must miss something because the radius estimated by LMS is $\sim 10^{13}$. Did we miss a $N_A$ in the equation @porphyrin?

it depends what units you are using, keep to molecules and metres and secs  and viscosity in pascal seconds then try using the Boltzmann constant instead of R the gas constant, the difference being Avogadro's number.

sorry, one last quick question for you @Antonin, for $\eta(T)$ are you using the Vogel-Fulcher function? Because in that case you end up with something like $D=\frac{k_B T}{6\pi \eta r_h}=\frac{k_B T}{6\pi r_h}\eta^{-1}=\frac{k_B T}{6\pi r_h}A^{-1}e^{-\frac{B}{T-C}}$, which is, essentially, a slightly modified Arrhenius function, so the theories match nicely up to a little parameter tweeking (the parameter C is a sort of threshold temperature arising from the phenomenological original VFT equation, I am not updated and therefore I don't know if it has a clear physical intepretation)

Sorry for the delay. I was using $\eta(T) = 10^{-3} \times 2.939 \times 10^{-2} \times e^{\frac{507.88}{T-149.3}}$, which is the Vogel-Fulcher function with parameters found on Wikipedia. This indeed gives the equation you wrote for $D$, and leaves only $r_h$ to fit to data if available, or to find it somewhere in tables ? In any case, it seems to me that this would be a good solution to the specific problem of a `good enough' approximation for biogeochemistry. Should I mark your comment as the answer?

If you want, yes, beacause it'll be difficult for me to write a complete answer before a week passes at best

Actually, I am not sure I can do that (sorry, new to the website). I don't think we are in a hurry, I will mark your answer as the solution when you have time, and if you do not, I can make the answer myself, referencing your comments
